# I want to move a random object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a square and I want that when I press the button, position the square to move randomly in the program ..

When I press the button nothing happens.

What is wrong with this code?

```
 var mycolor :ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    mycolor.color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF)

        var xposition:Number = Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50;
        var yposition:Number = Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50;
        trace(yposition);

        var rectangle:Shape = new Shape; // initializing the variable named rectangle
        rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
        rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0,0, 100, 100); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height
        rectangle.graphics.endFill();
        rectangle.transform.colorTransform = mycolor;
        addChild(rectangle);

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, generateRandom)

         function generateRandom(Event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            rectangle.graphics.moveTo(100, 70);
            btn.label = "asd";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [moveTo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#moveTo%28%29) is not used to determine a `position`, but to move the `current drawing position`.

You just have to write:

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, generateRandom);

function generateRandom(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    rectangle.x = Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50;
    rectangle.y = Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50;
}
```